# Do I have to do bundle install every time I open up a project with gem file?

Tags: rspec, rubygems

I work through multiple projects in a course. Each project come with the lib directory, the spec directory both of which contain ruby files. Each also comes with the gem file. I have rspec installed already. My question is that do I have to always do **bundle install** to get all the gems every time I work on a new project like that? Or is there a way to do bundle install once and for all?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you work alone (with codebase), you don't need to repeat `bundle install` all the time. It is necessary only when you add a new gem to your Gemfile.  But if you will work with a team, then need to be careful - you need to execute `bundle install` after receiving updates(because someone can add gem instead of you).

Also, You can monitor the Gemfile changes for knowledge about it.